# Does using a foreign key as a column in the django admin interface create a new database query for each row?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-queryset

I have a model relationship that looks like the following:

```
class Author(Model):
    first_name = CharField()

class Book(Model):
    title = CharField()
    author = ForeignKey(Author)
```

I want an admin interface like this:

```
class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author_name')

    def author_name(self, obj):
        return obj.author.name
```

Does this create a new query for each row, or is django smart about using a join here? What if the relation is 2 or more levels deep instead of just 1?

Using python 3.8, django 3.1, and Postgres 12.

Comment: Just tested this, seems yes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just tested this, and yes it seems to create a new query for each row. To confirm, you can use `DEBUG = True` in your settings and do something like this:

```
class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author_name')

    def author_name(self, obj):
        name = obj.author.name
        from django.db import connection
        print(len(connection.queries))
        return name
```

This will print the number of queries that are run, at the time when a row is rendered. You can observe that it increases as your rows are rendered.

Fortunately you can override `get_queryset` to add `select_related`, to improve the queries, so:

```
class BookAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'author_name')

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        queryset = super().get_queryset(request)
        return queryset.select_related('author')

    def author_name(self, obj):
        return obj.author.name
```

This gave me a constant number of queries which is ideal.

Answer (score 2):

See the docs FAQ: "[How can I see the raw SQL queries Django is running?](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/faq/models/#how-can-i-see-the-raw-sql-queries-django-is-running)"

Make sure your Django DEBUG setting is set to True. Then do this:

```
from django.db import connection
print(connection.queries)
```

This gives you all the SQL queries Django executed. From there you can inspect whether it uses joins or uses separate query for ForeignKey